# Rewrite rule only for article pages

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need help figuring out why sitemap generators are picking up roughly 64 URLs that do not exist. Based on my rewrite rules, I only want rewrites for any pages that look like “/article.php?id=#” to “article/#/article-title-here.

However, I’m getting all kinds of URLs generated when using a sitemap generator like /article/article.php/index.php or /article/index.php

Here is my htaccess rules

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect old article URLs to new URLs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /article/%1/%{QUERY_STRING}? [R=301,L]

# Rewrite article URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Is there something I need to change in this in order for it to only show my 5 main pages and 7 articles pages?

I have tried rewriting the rules multiple times and back checking with other sitemap generators.

Comment: This is most likely caused by incorrectly linking to relative URLs in your HTML source. However, you shouldn't be linking to `article.php` (and `index.php`) in your HTML source at all - this should be entirely invisible to the user (and sitemap generator).

Comment: Could you clarify on this? Why wouldn’t I want to link to my index.php page? For example, my logo in my header is a link that will take the user back to my homepage under a link ending in index.php

Comment: For example, you would link to `<a href="/">home</a>`, not `<a href="index.php">home</a>`. Note the first URL is root-relative, the second is _relative_.

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule appears to be trying to do opposite of what your question is saying.

The RewriteRule below will rewrite `/article.php?id=1234&title=article_title` to `/article/1234/article_title`

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite article URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)&title=([^/]*)$
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /article/%1/%2? [L]
```

Comment: Adding this eliminated the extra links but it created 7 broken links. All of which are the article pages.